# Check if a date entered by user is correctly formatted not not

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a script, where I get date as a string from a file which is created by user. Date can be in any date format. Need to check if the string is in correct date format or not. If it is a correct date format it should proceed with it, otherwise it should give error.

It can be any of the below formats -

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS
YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
YYYY/MM/DD
```

So far I have the code below-

```
datetime="2100-02-31"
if ! date -d "$datetime" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Not a date"
fi
```

But it is always giving "Not a date" output.

Comment: I assume you deliberately passing in a bad date?  Premature use of `>/dev/null` leads to missing a lot of informative error messages ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other dates? There is no 31 in Feb and of course it says "Not a date".

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the way you are taking input. Your original code should work. You can do it as you have attempted, or try using **command substitution** with the `date` command:

```
if ! $(date -d "$datetime" >/dev/null 2>&1); then
    echo "Not a date"
fi
```

With **bash version 4.3.33** it works with or without command substitution.

---

### Short Example

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r datetime; do

    echo "  $(date -d "$datetime")"
    if ! $(date -d "$datetime" >/dev/null 2>&1); then
        echo "Not a date"
    fi

done

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/datetime.txt
2012/10/21 19:51:31
2012/10/21 19:51
2012/10/21
something goofy
```

**Output**

```
$ bash chkdate.sh <dat/datetime.txt
  Sun Oct 21 19:51:31 CDT 2012
  Sun Oct 21 19:51:00 CDT 2012
  Sun Oct 21 00:00:00 CDT 2012
date: invalid date ‘something goofy’

Not a date
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix-up provided requires GNU date.
-E
Also, just as a user-interface element, you might want to let the user know what you are expecting.  The "not a date" answer doesn't help the user get to the correct format.